# How do I close an OS X application from the command line using a alias defined in my .bash_profile?

Tags: macos, command-line, alias, .bash-profile

I found the following shell script that can be used to tell an OS X application to quit:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo | osascript <<EOF
tell application "$*"
  quit
end tell
EOF
```

I have several simple alias commands in my .bash_profile and would like to add a "quit" command there instead of using this script.  I created the following, but it doesn't work:

```
alias quit='osascript -e "quit application \"$1\""'
```

I'm sure I've munged the command.  Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a function instead:

```
function quit {
osascript <<EOF
  tell application "$*" to quit
EOF
}
```

Comment: `tell application "$*" to quit` is more compact.

Comment: @DanielBeck: I've edited it to remove other redundancies as well, such as defining an alias whose only purpose is to call the function.  I left the HEREDOC-style quoting as I was having problems with alternatives and grew impatient ;)

Answer (score 2):

Aliases can't have parameters.  Aliases do a strict text substitution, where 'parameters' would kind of end up at the end.

I'd do a function, which can have parameters.

```
function quit
{
    if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "usage: quit _appname_" >&2
        return
    fi
echo | osascript <<EOF
tell application "$1"
  quit
end tell
EOF
}
```

Sorry, but I can't test this and verify today (no Mac), but the idea would work as a function.

Answer (score 0):

does it have to be an alias?

```
pkill Application
```

like, for example `pkill Safari` should do the same

Comment: Answer is for a proper answer, not another question, kindly read [how do I write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and edit your answer